# How do I remove a Git repo in TFS on-prem

Tags: git, tfs

I have created a Git repo through the web interface which is empty and unused. I would therefore like to remove it to avoid confusion. Looking at the [documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/delete-existing-repo) I should have a right-click option "Delete repository" alongside "Rename repository" but I only see the latter.

[image]

We are running Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 3 and I am Collection Administrator for the project in question. The permissions have not been changed from default so administrators have the permission to "Administer" on the repository.

There is also a TFVC repository in the same project and this one was created before the Git repository and it is the one that is actually being used. I have managed to hide is using permissions per the answer by @daniel-mann below, but would like to get rid of it fully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's the only Git repository in the project, it can't be deleted. If you decide not to proceed with using Git, you can lock it down so people can't access it.

Comment: I have now set permissions so that only administrators can see it, but I am still puzzled by the fact that I cannot remove it. There is already a TFVC repository that where there before I created the Git repro and is acutally the one being used.

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for, but I guess it is the best right now :-).